# Not able to connect to SQL database from nodejs

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database-connection, connection-string

So I'm new to node.js and I'm trying to make a connection to my local database to later insert data.
However when I execute my code it gives me a connection error with errorcode ESOCKET. I tried different ways to structure my connectionstring but it always gives me this error.

As I said I'm new to nodejs so I'm not really sure if the problem is my connection string or the port it uses (1433) or something entirely different.

#### code:

```js
const sql = require('mssql');
const config = {
  user: 'test',
  password: 'test',
  server: '.',
  database: 'Parkings'
}

async function databaseconn(parking){
   try{
       let pool = await sql.connect(config);
         await pool.request().query(`
          if not exists (select 1 from [Parking] where [Name] = '${parking.name}')
          begin
          insert into Parking ([Name], [Type], [Latitude], [Longtitude], [MaxCap]) 
          values ('${parking._name}', '${parking._type}', ${parking._latitude}, ${parking._longitude}, ${parking._maxcap})
          end
        `);
        await pool.request().query(`
        insert into [Entry] ([TimeDay], [Available], [ParkingId]) 
        values (${p._time}, ${p._available}, (select Id from Parking where Name = '${p._name}'))
        `);
      pool.close();
  } catch (err){
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

#### error:

```sh
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to .:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND .
    at Connection.<anonymous> (D:\Documenten\2019-2020\ParkingProject\nodejs_serverapp\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:68:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:428:26)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at Connection.socketError (D:\Documenten\2019-2020\ParkingProject\nodejs_serverapp\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1290:12)
    at D:\Documenten\2019-2020\ParkingProject\nodejs_serverapp\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1116:21
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.callback (D:\Documenten\2019-2020\ParkingProject\nodejs_serverapp\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:158:16)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:17) {
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  originalError: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to .:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND .
      at ConnectionError (D:\Documenten\2019-2020\ParkingProject\nodejs_serverapp\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:13:12)
      at Connection.socketError (D:\Documenten\2019-2020\ParkingProject\nodejs_serverapp\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1290:56)
      at D:\Documenten\2019-2020\ParkingProject\nodejs_serverapp\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1116:21
      at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.callback (D:\Documenten\2019-2020\ParkingProject\nodejs_serverapp\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:158:16)
      at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:17) {
    message: 'Failed to connect to .:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND .',
    code: 'ESOCKET'
  },
  name: 'ConnectionError'
}
```

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyx6v.png)

## SOLUTION

after a lot of trouble I fount the sollution to the issue thanks to a github post. You have to enable the TCP/IP protocol on your sql server and restart it. Guide in links below:

https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/799

https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/infinityinstaller/content/installermaster/tkenablenamedpipesandtcpipconnections.htm

Comment: Connections are very complex.  It all depends on your network setup, where the database is located, firewalls, port forwarding etc.  I do notice that you are attempting to connect with an anonymous user and no password on a local machine.  I would first start to see if you need a network address, and if you need a username and password to connect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
There is indeed an option to use a password and username, I now created a login and user for the database and added the user and password option to the config but it generates the same error output when I run the file.

Comment: Is the database on the local machine?  You will also need the ip of the machine in the connection string.

Comment: thanks, solved the issue, ill post the solution on this page as an edit